# Does a collection of selenium 2.0 extensions exist?

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver

I have recently started a automated testing project using selenium 2.0.  The api feels very low level and I'm looking to refactor some of the common stuff like form handling before writing too much repeating code.

I have searched a bit trying to find some conributed classes collection as I assume I'm not the first wanting to abstract some of the details of the driver away when writing the tests. I can't find any, however.

Where can I find reusable code for working with selenium 2.0?
I'm using Java but anything goes for inspiration.

Or would you recommend writing the utility classes from scratch or using the raw api?

Answer (score 1):

I wrote an article about [Selenium extensions in C#](http://www.vcskicks.com/selenium-extensions.php). It's only a few functions but you might find something interesting.

I agree that Selenium can lend itself to a lot of repetition and it would be interesting of the developers would include some higher level classes.

Comment: Thanks, I think some of those can come in handy.